# I need to set up paypal ipn to add tokens to accounts & transfer there steam id; stuck on error

Tags: php, paypal, runtime-error, paypal-ipn

The user enters there steamid into paypal somewhere and the paypal ipn listener(in the index.php) needs to get that steam id from paypal to add to there account. The part im stuck on is setting up the ipn verification since iv never done php or anything like that. Right now it gets this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Missing POST Data in /home/vol12_1/epizy.com/epiz_23648301/htdocs/PaypalIPN.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol12_1/epizy.com/epiz_23648301/htdocs/index.php(7): PaypalIPN->verifyIPN() #1 {main} thrown in /home/vol12_1/epizy.com/epiz_23648301/htdocs/PaypalIPN.php on line 57

Heres the code.

index.php

```
<?php namespace Listener;
require('PaypalIPN.php');
use PaypalIPN;
$ipn = new PaypalIPN();
// Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
$ipn->useSandbox();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {
    /*
     * Process IPN
     * A list of variables is available here:
     * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
     */
    echo "verifyed";
}
else{
     echo "not verifyed";
}
// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly.
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Riegn Of Darkness </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="search" placeholder=" Find account "/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

PayPalIPN.php 
I got this from here https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

```
<?php
class PaypalIPN
{
    /** @var bool Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used. */
    private $use_sandbox = false;
    /** @var bool Indicates if the local certificates are used. */
    private $use_local_certs = true;
    /** Production Postback URL */
    const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Sandbox Postback URL */
    const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
    const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
    const INVALID = 'INVALID';
    /**
     * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
     * should not be enabled in production).
     * @return void
     */
    public function useSandbox()
    {
        $this->use_sandbox = true;
    }
    /**
     * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
     * environments).
     * @return void
     */
    public function usePHPCerts()
    {
        $this->use_local_certs = false;
    }
    /**
     * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaypalUri()
    {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) {
            return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
        } else {
            return self::VERIFY_URI;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Verification Function
     * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function verifyIPN()
    {
        if ( ! count($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
        }
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
                if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                    if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                        $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
        }
        // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
        $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
        if ($this->use_local_certs) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'User-Agent: PHP-IPN-Verification-Script',
            'Connection: Close',
        ));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $http_code = $info['http_code'];
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly that code is expecting their to be some POST data and there is none. Are you sure you are using this code correctly?

Comment: this is structured strangely, the IPN listener should only be called by paypal, you are including it in index.php your public site page. You need to move it to its own distinct url, which you then tell paypal, either in the settings page on the paypal  admin, or in code that redirects the user for payment

Comment: ya sorry I guess I need to know how to set up the listener to listen for pay-pals ipn response. sorry for late reply